# String to Date conversion and comparing it with today's date

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My MongoDB looks something like this :

```json
{"_id": "1234aa", "maturity_dt":"2022-07-10", "countryCode":"BLG"},
{"_id": "123ab", "maturity_dt":"2022-07-30", "countryCode":"BLG"}
```

Note that *maturity_dt* is a string. I want to fetch the records with *maturity_dt* lesser than Today's date. Please help me build a query with **aggregation**. Since I have million records I cannot use foreach or any looping.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your mongo engine you are using in python you will need to format your query something like:

```
maturity_dt__ge=datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I would also make `maturity_dt` an index in your database.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the comparison with `$toDate` and `$expr`. Use `$$NOW` to reference today's date.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      {
        "$toDate": "$maturity_dt"
      },
      "$$NOW"
    ]
  }
})
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LsOSGYlKdy-) for your reference.

---

If an aggregation pipeline must be used, you can do like below:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            "$toDate": "$maturity_dt"
          },
          "$$NOW"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2DVbtGGH2Ne) for your reference.

Comment: @akshatahegde Consider accepting the answer to indicate the problem is solved and avoid duplicate effort from the community for investigation.